# How can i Align two nav bars that are under each other?

Tags: html, css

I tried placing two nav bars under each other but I am facing difficulty in aligning the second nav bar in respect to the first one. I didn't quite understand why the second nav bar does'nt float right.
Below are my html and css codes.

```css
.header_nav1 {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  color: #000;
  font-family: verdana;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  max-width: 1024px;
}

.header_nav1 ul li {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}

.header_nav2 {
  display: block;
  padding: 50px;
}

.header_nav2 ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 15px;
  max-width: 1024px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header_navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="header_nav1">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="/search/">Search</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <nav class="header_nav2">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/investors/">INVESTORS</a></li>
        <li><a href="/career/">CAREER</a></li>
        <li><a href="/our portfolio/">OUR PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="/solutions/">RETAIL SOLUTIONS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that it is caused by the container class.

You can either remove the container or change `float: right` to `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `float:right` instead use `display:inline`

why `inline`? `inline` - basically it starts with new line and occupy the whole parent size

I also combine both `header_nav1` and `header_nav2` on 1 CSS since both of it has the same layout

Here, check the snippet codes below and try seeing it also in full page. Hope it helps.

```css
.header_nav1, .header_nav2 {
    display: inline;
    color: #000;
    font-family: verdana;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    max-width:1024px;

}

.header_nav1 ul li{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

.header_nav2 ul li{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right:15px;
    max-width:1024px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header_navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="header_nav1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="/search/">Search</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <nav class="header_nav2">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/investors/">INVESTORS</a></li>
                <li><a href="/career/">CAREER</a></li>
                <li><a href="/our portfolio/">OUR PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="/solutions/">RETAIL SOLUTIONS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It works!! however, if I want both nav bars on the top right side of the screen perfectly aligned under each other what needs to be changed?

Comment: @BibekSharma -  you should use `display:inline-block` if you want to display both nav bars on 1 line. Check this fiddle link [display: inline-block](https://jsfiddle.net/grinex/e8uux34e/)